# Unable to understand what Javascript new Array( new Array(5,4,3,2,1,0),new Array())

Tags: javascript, arrays

Please tell me what this code is doing ,is it creating multi dimension array(which i think it is not) ?

code snippet..

```
 var hanoi_peg = new Array(
   new Array(  5,  4,  3,  2,  1,  0 ),
   new Array( -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 ),
   new Array( -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 )
 );
```

thanks..

Comment: It is creating an array of arrays. That is the definition of a multidimensional array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's creating an array of arrays. That's not quite the same as a multi-dimensional array, but it serves a similar purpose.

You can get the value 3, for instance, by doing this:

```
console.log(hanoi_peg[0][2]);
```

Normally you'd use array literal notation instead:

```
var hanoi_peg = [
   [  5,  4,  3,  2,  1,  0 ],
   [ -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 ],
   [ -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 ]
];
```

The difference between an array of arrays and a multi-dimensional array is that an array of arrays isn't stored in a single contiguous block of memory, and as a result can be *jagged*; the arrays in the second level don't all have to have the same number of elements. For instance, this is perfectly valid:

```
var a = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [1, 2, 3],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
];
```

In a true multi-dimensional array, there's one contiguous block of memory (in effect, one big single-dimensional array) and the compiler/runtime just does math on the indexes to find the right slot. For instance, a true 5x5 multi-dimensional array would be a single contiguous set of 25 slots, and when you asked for the entry at `[2][4]`, the compiler/runtime would turn that into `[(2*5)+4]` and return the contents of slot index 14.

But with an array of arrays, `[2][4]` is two different operations: First, get the entry at `[2]`, which is a reference to an array; then get the entry at `[4]` from that array.

Comment: +1 for `multi-dimension array` vs `array of arrays`. Also is there a way to create multi-dimension array in JS? Found a post [Creating 2-dimension array in JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/966225/how-can-i-create-a-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript) but even this is creating array of arrays

Comment: @Rajesh: Nope, JavaScript just doesn't have them yet. I say "yet" because we got [typed arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays) a few years back (although not officially until ES2015) and so it's always possible we'll get typed multi-dimensional arrays at some point. In the meantime, it's easy to create a class that emulates them if you need to, using a single-dimension array under the covers.

Comment: 0Thanks@T.J very nicely explained. :)

Answer (score 2):

Log it into your console and you will see that it creates an array of arrays and it serves for the same purpose.

```js
var hanoi_peg = new Array(
   new Array(  5,  4,  3,  2,  1,  0 ),
   new Array( -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 ),
   new Array( -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 )
 );

console.log(hanoi_peg);
```

To access each item you must use `double []` operators like this.
For accessing the first item of the first array you need to call

```
console.log(hanoi_peg[0][0]);
```

It is same as

```
var firstArray = hanoi_peg[0];
var firstItemOfFirstArray = firstArray[0]; // hanoi_peg[0][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Its creating an array of arrays

`new Array()` will return new array object. Array has 2 overrided constructors.

```
new Array(length)
```

This will return an array of specified length with all elements set as `undefined`. Note, this will only happen if length is integer. If you try `new Array('str')` this will return `['str']`. If you do `new Array(2.5)`, it will throw error as argument is numeric but not integer.

```
new Array(element list)
```

This will create an array with mentioned elements.

So when you do `new Array(new Array(1,2,3))`, `new Array(1,2,3)` will execute first returning `[1,2,3]` and then `new Array([1,2,3])` returning `[[1,2,3]]`

```js
var hanoi_peg = new Array(
   new Array(  5,  4,  3,  2,  1,  0 ),
   new Array( -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 ),
   new Array( -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 )
 );

console.log(hanoi_peg);
console.log(new Array('str'))
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is like this

```js
 //define array
            var hanoi_peg = [];
            //define 1st element and its array also
            hanoi_peg[0] = [5,  4,  3,  2,  1,  0];
            //define 2nd element and its array also
            hanoi_peg[1] = [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1];
            //define 3rd element and its array also
            hanoi_peg[2] = [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1];
            
        console.log("full array: "+JSON.stringify(hanoi_peg));
        /*
        [
         [5,  4,  3,  2,  1,  0],
         [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
         [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
        ]
        */
        console.log("first element of array: ",hanoi_peg[0]);//[5,  4,  3,  2,  1,  0];
        console.log("first element of inner array: "+hanoi_peg[0][0]);//5
```